Database of human signatures
I am looking for a dataset of images with signatures of humans with transparent background.
Purpose: We want to generate a set of sample data with hand signed documents for a specific type of document. These documents are generated, because there is no history of signatures on this specific document. Finally an ML algorithm should be trained to check for the existence of a signature on this document.
Optimally, these images should have a transparent background so they can be added to the document automatically without any further necessary processing steps.

There is a dataset on Kaggle: Handwritten Signature - Classification.
